# When passing html with styles defined in <style> tag to [innerHTML], prevent them from affecting entire app

Tags: angular

Basically I'm trying to have a `textarea` where the user can paste html (for emails), and a preview should be shown to a user. I tried implementing this by taking the html and passing it to a component to render the string as html, something like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

The problem with this is that if the user writes something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1 {color:red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The component will correctly render this html, but the styles will affect the entire app.

[image]

[image]

How can I make it so styles added by the user only affect the component on the bottom, which renders that html?

I know about styles scoped to the component, but this isn't exactly that as I'm not the one defining these styles.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood well, are you trying to make a component's view dynamic ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could say that. I want the user to be able to paste an email template, but to make sure it's correct, it should be rendered below as html. That's working fine actually that's not the problem. The problem is that any styles added there affect the entire app. I only want them to affect the email template.

Answer (score 0):

More information about nested components in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3).
You got your entire html replace because in deep you are doing so. Just let me clarify. You need a build a nestable component to talking to, and passes its the html view.

**app.component.ts (Container component)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  /* Bound property to get the html from your texarea element */
  html: any;
  pageTitle: string = 'I am a container';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- this styles classes are from bootstrap -->
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading" >
    {{ pageTitle }}
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Add Html:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" [(ngModel)]='html' ></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-child [htmlPreview]='html'></app-child>
  </div>  
</div>
```

And this is the code for your child component:
**appChild.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './appChild.component.html'
})
export class AppChildComponent {
  /* This is an Input property that tells Angular where to place the html from your textArea element */
  @Input() htmlPreview;

}
```

Finally your **appChild.component.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" [innerHtml]='htmlPreview'>
  <div class="panel-heading"></div>
</div>
```

/* Actually it does not matter what you put here, because it os going to be replace for the html from your text area. **BUT what it really matters is [innerHtml]='htmlPreview' is the tie to your Input property**  */

Do not forget to add your AppChild Component on your module:

```
...

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppChildComponent } from './appChild.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppChildComponent
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes this is pretty much what I did, it's not the problem. The problem is that if the user writes any styles in that textarea, then those styles affect the entire App. I want it to to only affect the innerHTML